# Read form-data on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am using multer to upload images to server. To do this, I send a `form-data` request from the client. It became necessary to check if the user is authorized. To do this, I send an object with a username and password. But there was a problem: I just can't get this data.

I use body-parser to get the request body.

I usually get the request body like this:

```js
const reqBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

With any other request, everything is fine, but with form-data `reqBody === {}`. What to do?

Route using multer:

```js
router.post('/image_for_profile',
    cors(corsOptions),
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const reqBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
            console.log(reqBody) // {}

            let status;

            upload(req, res, err => {
                let error = '';

                if (err) {
                    if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
                        error = 'The image size should not exceed 2mb';
                    }
                    if (err.code === 'EXTENTION') {
                        error = 'The file is neither jpg, nor jpeg, nor png';
                    }
                    status = error;
                }
            });

            return res.status(200).json({
                msg: status || 'OK',
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(500).json({
                msg: config.get('msgs.statuses.500err')
            });
        }
    }
);
```

The request:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're currently trying to access `req.body` before your `form-data`-parser has populated it. You need to move this into the `upload`-callback, multer will then have populated all text-based form-fields under `req.body` and there under the name of your form-field (`data` in your case).

```
// ...
 upload(req, res, err => {
      console.log(req.body.data); // will be populated here
      // ...
});
```

Comment: I tryed this and saw that the data is not parsed

Comment: What can I do ?

Comment: Definitely works for me, so there must be something else with your code. Can you share it on github or something else? Hard to say what's wrong without knowing more of your code..